# 300 Mbit/s network connection via 150 meter radio/wlan or 300 meter cable

Tags: wireless-networking, gigabit-ethernet, 802.11ac

I am searching for a possibility to send 300 Mbit/s net (as opposed to gross) over a distance of 150 meters. Are there any technologies available for private households and reasonable price? I would prefer to use 2,4 GHz technology, as I would be able to reuse my old directional radio antennas.

If radio (WLAN, Wifi, Wi-Fi) is not possible, a workaround would be a cable of 300 meters. But I heard that gigabit ethernet cables are only allowed to have a maximum length of 100 meters.

I was searching the internet and have found a lot of products, but most of them (all) mention only the gross network bandwidth, which often means, that the net network bandwidth is only half the given size.

Comment: I have no idea how you are using the terms "gross" and "net" here. They're very non-standard. But you want 5GHz because of the greater bandwidth available. Ubiquiti's LBE-5AC-Gen2, PBE-5AC-300, or NBE-5AC-16 might be an option.

Comment: Years ago, I have successfully transmitted with a few MBit over 1.5 km, but that was when 802.11g just came out. Build your own antenna. Easy for 2.4 GHz, but also possible for 5 GHz.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Make this an answer and I’ll accept it, as it seems the cheapest solution, compared to fibre cables and ethernet with amplfier/extender. It was new to me, that there are directional antennas with MIMO integrated in one single antenna. By the way you can find the gross and net bandwidths [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Local_Area_Network#Daten.C3.BCbertragungsraten) (“brutto” = gross, “netto” = net).

Answer (score 2):

A fibre connection would probably be your best bet, otherwise an Ethernet extender.

It could be possible to do this over wifi, but it's a bit of an ask to get the bandwidth and lack of interference to do this reliably (depending on your location and how directional your antennas are), especially on the 2.4 gig band.

Depending on the technology, gross bandwith can be the same as net bandwidth - certainly overhead is less then 50% - even in the case of WIFI.  One question might be whether the connection needs to be full or half duplex - ie if you need to be able to send and receive simultaneously - this is different to overhead though.

Comment: I assume full duplex, as it is an internet connection via fibre from Telefónica that I want to transmit and receive. I have ordered it, but it is not yet connected.